# How to add the values of multi-deminsional array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CODEIGNITER Cart Class. The following is a `VAR_DUMP` of the cart contents. I have a radio selection field which allows you to select a `SHIP` option. The problem is that my PHP is not getting the `SHIP` values but only returning the last item in cart's value and multiplying by the total number of cart items. How do I get the `SHIP` array from each item and sum the values?

## PHP

```
$ship_array = $this->cart->ship($item['rowid']); 
foreach ($ship_array as $index => $ship_option){
        #SHIPPING CALC
        
        $ship_total = 0;
        
        foreach ($cart as $item)
        {
         $ship_total += $ship_option;
        }
        
echo '<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="'. $ship_total .'" value="'. $index .'"/> UPS '. $index .' </label> '; }
```

^this code will only get the values from `ship` in the last item in the cart. The result will say that `ground` shipping is $43.35 (14.45 (ground shipping value * 3 total items)

Obviously this is wrong i need to add the shipping values from each `$item`

## VAR_DUMP of Arrays (all items in cart)

```
array (size=3)
  '554ed09a5f80917741359cc9da50a75c' => 
    array (size=8)
      'rowid' => string '554ed09a5f80917741359cc9da50a75c' (length=32)
      'id' => string '101' (length=3)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '112.5' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'Business Card' (length=13)
      'ship' => 
        array (size=3)
          'Ground' => float 9.73
          '2nd Day Air' => float 18.54
          'Overnight' => float 26.27
      'options' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Print Package' => string 'Pro' (length=3)
          'Design Package' => string 'Premium' (length=7)
      'subtotal' => float 112.5

  '675d8a197a25e6720af7ac05707fee40' => 
    array (size=8)
      'rowid' => string '675d8a197a25e6720af7ac05707fee40' (length=32)
      'id' => string '102' (length=3)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '446' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Booklet' (length=7)
      'ship' => 
        array (size=3)
          'Ground' => float 14.45
          '2nd Day Air' => float 22.57
          'Overnight' => float 34.12
      'options' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Print Package' => string 'Plus' (length=4)
          'Design Package' => string 'Ultimate' (length=8)
      'subtotal' => int 446

  'aea5d2f84151e65a0a1e50371aad26aa' => 
    array (size=8)
      'rowid' => string 'aea5d2f84151e65a0a1e50371aad26aa' (length=32)
      'id' => string '102' (length=3)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '325' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Booklet' (length=7)
      'ship' => 
        array (size=3)
          'Ground' => float 14.45
          '2nd Day Air' => float 22.57
          'Overnight' => float 34.12
      'options' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Print Package' => string 'Pro' (length=3)
          'Design Package' => string 'Premium' (length=7)
      'subtotal' => int 325
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$array = array(     
'554ed09a5f80917741359cc9da50a75c' => array('rowid' => '554ed09a5f80917741359cc9da50a75c','id' => '101','qty' => '1','price' => '112.5','name' => 'Business Card','ship' => array('Ground' => 9.73,'2nd Day Air' => 18.54,'Overnight' => 26.27),'options' => array('Pr Package' => 'Pro','Design Package' => 'Premium','subtotal' => 112.5)),
'675d8a197a25e6720af7ac05707fee40' => array('rowid' => '675d8a197a25e6720af7ac05707fee40','id' => '102','qty' => '1','price' => '446','name' => 'Booklet','ship' => array('Ground' => 14.45,'2nd Day Air' => 22.57,'Overnight' => 34.12),'options' => array('Pr Package' => 'Plus','Design Package' => 'Ultimate','subtotal' => 446)),
'aea5d2f84151e65a0a1e50371aad26aa' => array('rowid' => 'aea5d2f84151e65a0a1e50371aad26aa','id' => '102','qty' => '1','price' => '325','name' => 'Booklet','ship' => array('Ground' => 14.45,'2nd Day Air' => 22.57,'Overnight' => 34.12),'options' => array('Pr Package' => 'Pro','Design Package' => 'Premium','subtotal' => 325)));


$shipArray = $array ; // Replace with $this->cart->ship($item['rowid']);
$shipTotal = array("prize"=>0,"ground"=>0,"air"=>0,"overnight"=>"0");
foreach ($shipArray as $index => $shipOption){
    $shipTotal['prize'] += $shipOption['qty'] * $shipOption['price'];
    $shipTotal['ground'] += $shipOption['ship']['Ground'];
    $shipTotal['air'] += $shipOption['ship']['2nd Day Air'];
    $shipTotal['overnight'] += $shipOption['ship']['Overnight'];
}

var_dump($shipTotal);
```

Output

```
array
  'prize' => float 883.5
  'ground' => float 38.63
  'air' => float 63.68
  'overnight' => float 94.51
```

Comment: This returns the following array after spelling correction. How do I get the value from the array to replace the `0` I do not know the proper syntax. Thank you. 
`array (size=7)
  0 => string 'price' (length=5)
  'Ground' => int 0
  '2nd Day Air' => int 0
  'Overnight' => int 0
  'price' => int 0
  'ground' => int 0
  'air' => int 0`

Comment: Its not possible see http://codepad.viper-7.com/mch2QH .... except am been given the wrong var_dump that is why i had to reconstruct the array @fabio

Comment: hey thanks for taking your time but this is still returning the values in the `$shipTotal` so all i see is `0,0,0,0`. I made `$shipArray = $this->cart->ship($item['rowid']);` If i just do a vardump on `$shipArray = $this->cart->ship($item['rowid']);` I get `array (size=3)
  'Ground' => float 14.45
  '2nd Day Air' => float 22.57
  'Overnight' => float 34.12` which is based on the last item in the cart. Problem is getting all the items in the cart. Do you have any other ideas? Perhaps I need to create a function in the cart library file? thank you for your help

Comment: Not sure what type of cart you are using just answered your question `How to add the values of multi-deminsional array?` .... Am sure they would be an option to get all items in the cart .. your var_dump shows more than 1 item

Comment: I am using the cart class in codeigniter (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html) yes i can easily dump the cart contents with `$this->cart->contents();` the problem is dumping just the `ship` array from each cart item.

Comment: When you run `foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items)` what does `var_dump($items)` look like

Comment: i got it to work. i just had to replace `$this->cart->ship($item['rowid']);` `$array = $this->cart->contents();` Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

move

```
$ship_total = 0;
```

to outsize of the first foreach loop.

Edit use this:

```
$ship_array = $this->cart->ship($item['rowid']); 
$ship_total = 0; //this moved
foreach ($ship_array as $index => $ship_option){
        #SHIPPING CALC

        foreach ($cart as $item)
        {
         $ship_total += $item['ship'][$ship_option] * $item['qtq']; //this changed
        }
        echo '<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="'. $ship_total .'" value="'. $index .'"/> UPS '. $index .' </label> ';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however I get the same result. no change.

Comment: There, I didn't realize you had some other issues as well. I think I fixed those.